# Why is my rock/paper/scissors game getting the same random number for multiple function calls?

Tags: javascript, function, math, random, console

I have made a functioning (if possibly extremely verbose) game of rock/paper/scissors.

If I run the game by calling the function once over and over the 'computer's' choice is properly randomised and therefore the outcome of the game is as intended. However if I call the function thrice at once, with "rock", "paper" and "scissors" as my guesses, the computer's choice is randomised, but the same choice is applied to all three calls to the function.

Thank you in advance. Here's the problemo...

JS:

```
const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

const randChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);

const compChoice = choices[randChoice];

const playGame = (you, comp) => {
  if (you === "paper" && comp === "rock") {
    console.log(you + " beats " + comp + ". YOU WIN!")
  } else if (you === "rock" && comp === "paper") {
    console.log(comp + " beats " + you + ". YOU LOSE!")
  } else if (you === "rock" && comp === "scissors") {
    console.log(you + " beats " + comp + ". YOU WIN!")
  } else if (you === "scissors" && comp === "rock") {
    console.log(comp + " beats " + you + ". YOU LOSE!")
  } else if (you === "scissors" && comp === "paper") {
    console.log(you + " beats " + comp + ". YOU WIN!")
  } else if (you === "paper" && comp === "scissors") {
    console.log(comp + " beats " + you + ". YOU LOSE!")
  } else if (you === comp) {
    console.log("You both chose " + you + ". That's a draw.")
  }
};
```

If I call the function once, the game works...

```
playGame("rock", compChoice);
```

If I call the function thrice, the computer's choice is the same for all three matches, therefore I will win, lose and draw every time, albeit in a random order...

```
playGame("rock", compChoice);
playGame("paper", compChoice);
playGame("scissors", compChoice);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`randChoice` is called once, `compChoice` is evaluated once based on that, so when you `playGame`, you're passing the same computer choice each time.

`playGame` should be modified to perform the choice each time the game is played:

```js
    const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
       
    const playGame = (you, comp) => {
      var randChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
      var compChoice = choices[randChoice];
      
      if (you === "paper" && comp === "rock") {
        console.log(you + " beats " + comp + ". YOU WIN!")
      } else if (you === "rock" && comp === "paper") {
        console.log(comp + " beats " + you + ". YOU LOSE!")
      } else if (you === "rock" && comp === "scissors") {
        console.log(you + " beats " + comp + ". YOU WIN!")
      } else if (you === "scissors" && comp === "rock") {
        console.log(comp + " beats " + you + ". YOU LOSE!")
      } else if (you === "scissors" && comp === "paper") {
        console.log(you + " beats " + comp + ". YOU WIN!")
      } else if (you === "paper" && comp === "scissors") {
        console.log(comp + " beats " + you + ". YOU LOSE!")
      } else if (you === comp) {
        console.log("You both chose " + you + ". That's a draw.")
      }
    };
```

Comment: Ah, so randChoice is only calculated at the beginning and will only change if I re-run the program. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

> const randChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);

is a constant, you want to recalculate randChoice  and compChoice in between each play

Comment: I understand that I want it to recalculate each time. I just can't conceptualise why it isn't.

Could you explain what the difference between manually recalling the function and instructing it to recall the function multiple times is, please?

I'm having a little difficulty grasping why there is no new randomisation when the argument of compChoice is passed to the function. I hope I'm making some sense :)